# Insert two arrays in tableView - Error connecting

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Edited:

I'm trying to insert two arrays into one tableview with two cell labels. But not really sure how I can convert it all and make it work. Here is my code so far.

In the top of the main ViewController (Where the tableView is)

```
class ScoreBoardViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource

    var countedArray: [String] = []
    var nameArray: [String] = []

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    var list: [pointsTxt] = []
```

> Additional info: I've added the ***self.tableView.delegate = self***

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return list.count

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let listPath = list[indexPath.row]
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "pointsCell") as! ScoreCell
        cell.setCell(list: listPath)

        return cell
    }

    func createArray() -> [pointsTxt]
    {
        var tempTxt: [pointsTxt] = []

        let txt = pointsTxt(person: nameArray, points: countedArray)

        tempTxt.append(txt)

        self.list = tempTxt
        self.tableView.reloadData()

        return list
    }
```

---

Class for the cell

```
class ScoreCell: UITableViewCell
{

    @IBOutlet weak var person: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var points: UILabel!


    func setCell(list: pointsTxt)
    {
        person.text = list.person
        points.text = list.points
    }
}
```

> ERROR: Cannot assign value of type '[String]' to type 'String?'

---

Class for the array

```
class pointsTxt
{
    var person: [String] = []
    var points: [String] = []

    init(person: [String] = [], points: [String] = [])
    {
        self.person = person
        self.points = points
    }
}
```

I hope you understand what I need. Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you connect the outlets to the viewController? it should be something like var label = UILabel() and then you set it like this: label.text = points otherwise you should look up how to connect Outlets from the Storyboard

Comment: @PaFi Yep, I did

Comment: can you show the code how you connected the outlets?

Comment: Give me two minutes. :) Thanks

Comment: you also have to downcast to the correct UITableviewClass, I will post an answer as a example. Edit: Did you create a UITableView Subclass?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/swXVXJh - @PaFi

Comment: @PaFi I did not create an additional subclass.

Comment: Please show the rest of your code.

Comment: @drewster Sorry for the time. Had a really busy day. But check the edit. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to follow the following steps when creating a custom tableViewCell:

1. Subclass UITableViewCell
2. Add your Outlets to that subclass
3. register your subclass to the TableView
4. code Example for your rowAtIndexPath function:

.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if indexPath.row < nameArray.count {

        // load from customerDetails array
        let names = nameArray[indexPath.row]

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "listCell", for: indexPath) as! UITableViewSubclassCell
        cell.person.text = names

        return cell
    } else {
        // load from customerDetails2 array
        let points = countedArray[indexPath.row - nameArray.count]

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "listCell", for: indexPath) as! UITableViewSubclassCell
        cell.person.text = points
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: somehow the code formatting does not work, but do you get what I mean?

Comment: I added a dot between the numbered list and the code and now it is formatted correctly. There is some weird stuff going on with lists followed by code and right now I don’t know how to handle it correctly, hence the “hack”.

Comment: @PaFi Alright, so. I've added the subclass etc. But getting this when inserting the arrays. -> https://imgur.com/a/1ATWevk

Comment: you have to access nameArray through an index for example like nameArray[0]